# Search a website using excel vba with excel data and extract the active state in flowchart of search result and mapping it into column

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am hoping someone can help....

I have around 7000 values in a excel spreadsheet that I need to search in a website and then record active state of result flowchart from the website to be inputted back into the excel spreadsheet. Since I am new to macros web scrape I used to automate web code modified input ids for the website which I want to extract information (https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/). I am a bit confused in how to apply if condition to get the active state having seven classes in flowhchart, Here is the flow chart.

Now that I have access codes each will be on different stage, I only want to pick the state and put it in column E in front of the access code(currently doing manually)

I am unclear how to extract that info being new to this type of web data extraction - any help would be incredible!

Here is my code:(couldn't be able to change for mentioned web after this)

```
objIE.document.getElementById("btnPesquisa").Click
```

Code:

```
'start a new subroutine called SearchBot
Sub SearchBot()
 
    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
    Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
    Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link
 
    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
 
    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True
 
    'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
    objIE.navigate "https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/"
 
    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
 
    'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
    objIE.document.getElementById("SenhaAcesso").Value = _
      Sheets("Guy Touti").Range("D2").Value
 
    'click the 'go' button
    objIE.document.getElementById("btnPesquisa").Click
 
    'wait again for the browser
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
 
    'the first search result will go in row 2
    y = 2
 
    'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with class of 'result__a'...
    For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("result__a")
 
        '...get the href link and print it to the sheet in col C, row y
        result = aEle
        Sheets("Guy Touti").Range("E" & y).Value = result
 
        '...get the text within the element and print it to the sheet in col D
        Sheets("Guy Touti").Range("D" & y).Value = aEle.innerText
        Debug.Print aEle.innerText
 
        'is it a yellowpages link?
        If InStr(result, "yellowpages.com") > 0 Or InStr(result, "yp.com") > 0 Then
            'make the result red
            Sheets("Guy Touti").Range("C" & y).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            'place a 1 to the left
            Sheets("Guy Touti").Range("B" & y).Value = 1
        End If
 
        'increment our row counter, so the next result goes below
        y = y + 1
 
    'repeat times the # of ele's we have in the collection
    Next
 
    'add up the yellowpages listings
    Sheets("Guy Touti").Range("B1").Value = _
      Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Guy Touti").Range("B2:B100"))
 
    'close the browser
    objIE.Quit
 
'exit our SearchBot subroutine
End Sub
```

I did try this first but after a while started searching for a better way. Can you help????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the POST XHR request the page makes to get data and use the classnames to limit to nodes with either `active1` or `active3`. Take the last node in that nodelist and extract the step number and convert colour via lookup (if wanted). With 7,000 requests it might be considerate to add a delay in every 50 requests, or less, of 1-2 seconds. You can `i mod 50` to determine this in the loop and use `Application.Wait Now + Timeserial(0,0,2)`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetStatus()

    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object, colourLkup As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, senhas(), i As Long, results()

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    senhas = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("D2:D" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row))

    ReDim results(1 To UBound(senhas))

    Set colourLkup = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    colourLkup.Add "active1", "green"
    colourLkup.Add "active3", "orange"

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    For i = LBound(senhas) To UBound(senhas)
        If senhas(i) <> vbNullString Then
            With xhr
                .Open "POST", "https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/Home/GetEstadoProcessoAjax", False
                .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                .send "SenhaAcesso=" & senhas(i)
                html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With

            Dim nodes As Object, classinfo() As String

            Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll(".active1, .active3")

            classinfo = Split(nodes(nodes.Length - 1).className, Chr$(32))
            results(i) = Replace$(classinfo(1), "step", vbNullString) & "-" & colourLkup(classinfo(2))
        End If
        Set nodes = Nothing
    Next
    ws.Cells(2, 5).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
End Sub
```

Comment: dear getting error object variable or with block variable not set  in line  "classinfo = Split(nodes(nodes.Length - 1).className, Chr$(32))"

Comment: What is the value of senhas(i) at this point - when error occurs? And are your values positioned as shown in image?

Comment: And what is the value of _i_ ?

Comment: I=122 and senhas(i)=empty but my column E remains unfilled from the row2 however I suppose it should fill column E till 122

Comment: do you have a value in D123? There shouldn't be any empty values in column D for your lookups.

Comment: no dear 123 is empty actually, can you adjust code to do nothing for empty cell instead of breaking code

Comment: The code is running now dear but it is taking too much time, still running!

Comment: dear whenever there is some wrong number code breaks up it should leave that and go to next I believe.

Comment: please can you help in sorting above comment issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205254/discussion-between-m-faizan-farooq-and-qharr).